# Getting main domain name from referring website

Tags: c#, asp.net, blogspot

We are relying on refering urls when we pick up requests from users who installed our widget, it's just and iframe, similar to Google plus button, Facebook Like etc.

Recently we noticed that Google's blogspot blogs can be accessed using multiple urls with different ending like:

```
*.blogspot.com
*.blogspot.fr 
*.blogspot.co.uk 
...
```

Now our database is getting filled with duplicate websites.
Is there any way to get real address every time like *.blogspot.com

Are there any other websites that do such a thing, make themsalves available through different domains without redirecting to real one, or is blogspot specific?

How does facebook handle this, do people that own blog on blogspot have different like count for different domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [dns lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx) for CNAME entries.

```
var host = Dns.GetHostByName("www.blogspot.com").HostName;
// host == "blogger.l.google.com"
```

If the host DNS contains a CNAME, the `HostName` property will return the CNAME.

The following description my be helpful:

> A CNAME record or Canonical Name record is a type of resource record
>   in the Domain Name System (DNS) that specifies that the domain name is
>   an alias of another, canonical domain name. Here "canonical" usually
>   means: a more generally accepted or standard name.
>   ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record))

Comment: @Istern I think you missunderstood the question, I need to get main address  for the website which is in this case blog.blogspot.com but referring site address is blog.blogspot.fr, because they are sam blogs with different addresses and I need to get real one.

Comment: @user1010609 both respond to the same ip and are dns alias for blogger.l.google.com. There's not a principal one.